Is it possible to connect the old bell to the new quartz clock
I have old quartz clock which has a bell as in the picture.

but unfortunately the electronics of that old watch are missing. however, I have, as in the picture, a new clock with a speaker.

the sound is terrible, that is, the melody played by that speaker is terrible.
so I'm interested in what you think, if I connect the old bell to the new clock, would the bell work?
for example, if it's three o'clock, then the bell should ring three times, etc... on the same principle, this speaker works, only instead of the bell, it plays a melody.
if not, is it possible to make some pcb diy, so the bell can be used with the new clock?
Thank you

This probably wouldn’t be simple to do.
For the bell, the clock would output a series of pulses depending on the time, so one pulse at 1:00, two pulses at 2:00, etc.
For the speaker it would output something like an audio signal, which could be regular audio if it’s a dynamic speaker or possibly square waves or PWM if it’s a piezo speaker.
The problem then becomes converting the audio to pulses, and getting the correct number of pulses and timing. If it just plays the same tune each hour there would be no easy way to know what hour it is to ring the bell the correct number of times.
Your best option is probably to look for a clock that does what you want rather than trying to adapt one that doesn’t.
